# jquery curvy corners on table & full page div tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the jquery curvy corners plugin I can get this working on a div tag, but as most of the content is empty, and the width/height is 90% of the page the corners are only rounded at the top.

Also when trying to round the corners of a table this doesnt work, is it possible?

```
<div id="content" class="content">
    <table id="nav_links" class="nav_links" cellpadding="7">
    <tr>
    <td class="nav_background"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>       
    </tr>
</table>

</div>


<script>
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $('.content').corners();
   $('.nav_links').corners();
});
</script>
```

Css:

```
.nav_links 
{
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
   border-collapse: collapse;                   
 }
   #content
 {

    width: 90%; 
    height: 780px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: #003366;      
  margin-left: auto ;
   margin-right: auto ;
```

}

Any idea?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [the code](http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/jquery.curvycorners.min.js) has a parameter in the `settings` object called `validTags` and is set like to `validTags: ["div"]` -- I don't have experience with this plugin, but it seems like perhaps when you initialize it you can add 'table' as a value, like `validTags: ["div","table"]` -- though it's possible that the actual way the plugin works will only be successful if you operate on a `<div>`.

Comment: Hmmm they seem to round in firefox, and the whole div tag is rounded aswel, in IE only the top of the div tag is rounded and the table isnt...

Comment: Just found http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/ - hosted on Google Code, maybe a more current version of the code?